# The angle at which segment is visible in the half-plane. Harmonicity of the function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I try to solve the following problem:

Consider a half-plane on the boundary of which the segment lies. In this (open) half-plane, consider the angle at which this segment is visible. Is this function harmonic?

My attempt

Let $[x,y]$ is the segment and let $\omega$ is the point in the half-plane. The angle $x\omega y$ is described as $\arg(x-\omega)-\arg(y-\omega)$.

I don't understand why this function is harmonic.

Can you help please?

Thank you.

Comment: The argument function (defined continuously on some appropriate domain) is the imaginary part of a holomorphic function so it is harmonic

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your time. And I have one question yet. Possibly it is a folly question. In which domains this function(argument function) is continuous?

Comment: On any domain that avoids zero and is simply connected (largest such is the plane minus a half line ending at the origin);

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your answer and for your explanation.

Comment: Happy to be of help